# applying a template change in joomla1.6

Tags: joomla

How can we apply a new template in Joomla1.6 . I have  a custom template created. How do i enable it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think is to upload your new template folder to the 'templates' folder, and then hit the "Discovery" located in the Extension Manager: Install.

also try to upload the ziped folder to

Extension Manager in 1.6 instead of Extensions > Install/Uninstall

thanks